# Javascript: lexical scoping issue using new keyword constructor

Tags: javascript

i have problem about scoping in javascipt. I tried to create new object using the "new" keyword without any problem. The code looks like this

```
"use strict";

 function Person() {
     this.name = "john doe";
     console.log(this.name);
 }

 Var foo = new Person()
```

The problem i encountered is when i try to add inner function the scope of the name variable becomes undefined inside the inner function

```
 "use strict";

 function Person() {
         this.name = "john doe";

         Function speak() {
                   console.log("my name is" + this.name);
         }

         speak();
  }

  var foo = new Person();

 //error: "cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
```

Can somebody explained what seems to be the problem? Thank guys

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable

Comment: Also in w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it)

Comment: I think its not a duplicate my issue is about lexical scopping. I declared this.name one level up higher to my inner function speak. If the lexical scoping is applied the inner function should be able to use the 'this.name' declared inside Person function which is not.

Comment: I think i know the problem if im not wrong. This is sumthing to do with "new" keyword. Using "new" keyword created a plain object not a function(which is an object also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Strict mode** when you are creating the object with `new Person()`, `this` refers to the `window` object which does not have the `property` called `name`. `property` called `name` belongs to the `Person` object.
Thus you are getting error `cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

User another variable to hold the value of `Person` object's `this` to use that inside the inner function.

`var thatObj = this;`

```js
"use strict";

function Person() {
  this.name = "john doe";
  var thatObj = this;
  function speak() {
    console.log("my name is: " + thatObj.name);
  }

  speak();
}

var foo = new Person();
```

Comment: Can u add some explainations why this is undefined and why storing this to an object works? Thanks

Comment: @arnoldemzi, I have added the reason behind. Please have a look ...thanks.

Comment: You should mention about "use strict" but i upvoted it for solving then problem

Comment: @arnoldemzi, I have updated the answer. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give `speak` the same scope as `this`. It should be noted that this will also make it a public function, so `speak` can be called from outside of the `Person` class.

```js
function Person() {
    this.name = "john doe";

    this.speak = function() {
        console.log("my name is " + this.name);
    };
         
    this.speak();
}

var foo = new Person();
```

Comment: Yhup this code works. But adding this to speak wont make it inner function anymote it now becomes a funtion of person object

Comment: @arnoldemzi Another option is to keep your original code, except change the call from `speak();` to `speak.call(this);`

Answer (score 0):

`this` is determined by how a function is invoked, not where the function is defined. Since `this.name` is inside its own scope it has lost a reference to `this.name` instead it is referencing a global window object.

It is important to be aware of the fact when using `this` keyword **inside of nested functions** you are more than likely going to lose reference to the object that you are inside of and your `this` keyword will end up referencing the global object.

There is also another solution to your example using `call` or `apply` methods.
`call` and `apply` will allow you to change the value of `this` when function is executed.

```js
'use strict';

function Person () {
    this.name = 'john doe';

    function speak () {
        console.log('my name is: ' + this.name);
    }

    speak.call(this);
}

var foo = new Person();
```